# MySQL: is Partitioning a good way to handle deletes?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, partitioning

I have an MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE responses (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    other_id INT NOT NULL,
    details TEXT,
    deleted BOOLEAN,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Users could delete records in `responses`.

My plan is to use the field `deleted` to implement deletion. Any time a user deletes a record, I'll set `deleted` to `1`.

Every now and then I might want to get rid of all the deleted records or to archive them. I'm thinking of using partitioning to make that faster:

```
PARTITION BY LIST(deleted) (
    PARTITION pActive VALUES IN (0),
    PARTITION pDeleted VALUES IN (1)
);
```

My question is would this make the act of deletion slower? Now that when I change a record's "deleted" field, MySQL would need to move the record to an entirely different partition. That seems like it could be slow.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I'd expect the transition between the two states to be slower for sake of being passed between the partitions.  But deleted/non-deleted queries on existing values would be faster, though queries that don't involve the deletion status wouldn't be improved.

It's all about what is the most common operation in the table, and accepting that there can be compromises.

Answer (score 3):

I've been on a project in the past where this approach was used, and my personal feeling is that it's not the best approach. I think it's better to just delete the records. When you have a flag like this, everyone who uses your database has to understand that records that exist in the table might not be "real" records, depending on whether or not the deleted flag is set. It just makes the database less intuitive, and harder to use in my opinion.

If you're concerned about performance, I'd look at properly allocating your tablespaces, and you can still employ a partitioning scheme. You could partition the data by year and month (if you need that level of granularity) to help with the performance.

But I would avoid the deleted flag. On the project I worked on, it just became a real headache. For example, what if somebody tries to insert another record exactly the same as the one that was "deleted" (deleted here means deleted flag is true). Do you set deleted to false on the existing record, or do you insert another brand new record? If you insert a brand new record, how do you define your primary key on the table since now you have 2 records with the same key? Do you make `deleted` part of the key? The point is that you have to deal with all those types of non-trivial issues.

Comment: I've worked on systems that use a "soft delete" approach like this.  They wanted to know how many were created in total vs. what was actually used in the system.  Some stuff was deleted based on supercedeing/subsequent things, but they wanted to be able to restore if necessary.  Just depends on the business rules, but it can impact resources/drive space...

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I just remember it was a nightmare on the project I worked on. I think a better approach would be to use a trigger to copy the records to another table if you want to save the deleted data, but I would avoid the deleted flag like the plague :). Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @dcp: A trigger to move things requires a duplicate table -- none of the DBAs I knew of at the time would allow such a thing in their data model.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - We call these audit tables. So I would have person and person_audit. The person_audit table would track inserts/updates/deletes to the person table. That's the approach I like to use because it give the full audit trail. I haven't seen DBA's that object to it. Maybe the word "audit" is what is needed to make them feel better about the extra table :). Anyway, if DBA's object to having audit tables, I'd really have to question them.

Comment: I believe this is a viable approach, especially if some way to undelete is required. But sometimes the "audit table" method may be better... depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @sleske - I'm not saying it's not a viable approach, I'm just saying be prepared for the headaches that can occur if you don't think it through carefully, like considering the scenario I mentioned in my answer. I just prefer the audit table approach, it's more intuitive in my opinion and easier to work with.